# Converting Pandas groupby.groups result into dataframe, using index tuple value as row and columns name of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

the resuts of my groupby.groups return :

```
{(2014, 36): [2], (2014, 41): [3, 4], (2013, 10): [0], (2014, 48): [5], (2014, 37): [1]}
```

i want to convert it into a dataframe that will looks like :

```
      2013 2014
10    1    0
36    0    1
37    0    1
41    0    2
48    0    1
```

-- adds --
here is my workflow to the groupby.groups results :

```
def tr_epoch(epoch):
       y,wn,dn = epoch.isocalendar()
       return y, wn

d = [1362826800, 1410260400, 1409828400, 1412766000, 1412769600, 1417262400 ] 
l = map(lambda x:  tr_epoch(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x)), d)
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['year','week_idx'])
res = df.groupby(['year','week_idx']).groups
```

-- adds -- 
in pythonic way, using iteration,  i will do :

```
def  to_dict(k,v):
    yr, wk = k
    return {'week': wk, yr: len(v)}

data =  map(lambda(k,v): to_dict(k,v), res.iteritems())
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, index='week').fillna(0).sort()
```

But i am sure, there is a pandas way to do.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example (original dataframe before groupby)? Where do the values in your output come from?

Comment: Hi joris, i edit my post to add the process that bring me to the groupby.groups result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to calculate the size of each group? Then you can do:

```
In [31]: df.groupby(['year','week_idx']).size()
Out[31]:
year  week_idx
2013  10          1
2014  36          1
      37          1
      41          2
      48          1
dtype: int64
```

To reshape this to the expected output, we can now use `unstack` to move the 'year' index level from the rows to the columns (and the use `fillna` to get 0's):

```
In [33]: df.groupby(['year','week_idx']).size().unstack(0).fillna(0)
Out[33]:
year      2013  2014
week_idx
10           1     0
36           0     1
37           0     1
41           0     2
48           0     1
```

Comment: thanks a lot joris, i feel stupid, unstack was not in my scope of known function :-(